# Resuming an NSTimer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nstimer

The other questions I've seen on this didn't help. I want to be able to start, pause, and then resume the NSTimer. I know how to start the NSTimer. I also know that you can't 'pause' the NSTimer but you can invalidate it. But what would I have to do if I wanted to resume it keeping the same time I had when I stopped the timer? Here's the code:

```
var startTimer = NSTimeInterval()
var timer = NSTimer()
@IBOutlet var displaylabel: UILabel! 
@IBAction func start(sender: UIButton) {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTimer = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
}
@IBAction func stop(sender: UIButton) {
timer.invalidate()
}
@IBAction func resume(sender: UIButton) {
// Code needed
}
func updateTime() {
    let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTimer
    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)
    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)
    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)
    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)
    let fraction = UInt8(elapsedTime * 100)
    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)
    let strFraction = String(format: "%02d", fraction)
    displaylabel.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds).\(strFraction)"
}
```

Thanks in advance. Anton

Comment: Why the dislike (-1)?

Comment: `NSTimer` is not suited for that design; it's not a "stopwatch" (just something that triggers a function call at a specified later time, optionally repeating). You will have to implement the counter yourself. Try searching for `CADisplayLink` (Core Animation Display Link).

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks... Can you please give me the code if possible?

Comment: Just start a new timer using a time interval calculated as the time that remained until your next tick.  You're almost there.

Comment: You definitely do not need `CADisplayLink`.

Comment: Ok @par ... Thanks for the info. I know how I would create a new timer but how would create a timer using a time interval calculated as the time that remained until your next tick?

Comment: He definitely can not do it with `NSTimer` alone. `CADisplayLink` may be overkill, but can get the job done.

Comment: Yes you can.  Setup a repeating timer and adjust the `fireDate` property before you schedule it.  I don't want to completely give away the answer to Anton's homework though.

Comment: @NicolasMiari will the game lag more if I use CADisplaLink instead of Nstimer?

Comment: CADisplayLink is more reliable than NSTimer.

Comment: @par will the game lag more if I use CADisplaLink instead of NStimer?

Comment: Game lag depends on a lot more than just the choice of timer.  You should ask a separate question if you'd like to explore an aspect of that topic though--comments aren't an appropriate place for general discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `CADisplayLink` for two reasons:

1. You'll update the screen as often as possible and not waste extra battery life trying to update it more often than possible. All iOS devices (except the iPad Pro under rare circumstances) update the screen at most 60 times per second. Scheduling your timer for 0.01 seconds means you're trying to update the screen at least 40 times per second more often than necessary.
2. You can pause and resume a `CADisplayLink`.

Handling pause requires a little thought. What you want to do is record the time when you pause (separately from the start time), and then when you resume, increase the start time by the time elapsed since pausing.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var startTime = NSTimeInterval(0)
    private var pauseTime = NSTimeInterval(0)
    private var displayLink: CADisplayLink!

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: "displayLinkDidFire")
        displayLink.paused = true
        displayLink.addToRunLoop(NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop(), forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }

    @IBAction func startWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        displayLink.paused = false
    }

    @IBAction func resumeWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        startTime += NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - pauseTime
        displayLink.paused = false
    }

    @IBAction func stopWasTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        pauseTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        displayLink.paused = true
    }

    func displayLinkDidFire() {
        let elapsedTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate() - startTime
        label.text = String(format: "%02.0f:%05.2f", floor(elapsedTime / 60), elapsedTime)
    }

}
```

Comment: I just implemented your solution to update my video progress `UISlider`. However, the thumb slider is moving too fast. How do I make it tick once a second?...I was using `NSTimer` before so I'm not familiar with `CADisplayLink`

Comment: Since there is no slider in my solution, I don't understand what your problem is. Maybe you should post a new question.

Comment: @Pangu Use displayLink.frameInterval, e.g. 60 = 1 second