# Can't fire timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm currently having trouble firing a timer in my app. Here's what my code looks likes

```
func action() {
  //Paused
  timer.invalidate()

    let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Quit?", message: "Are you sure you want to quit?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes!", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        //Quit
    }))

    refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No!", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        //Dismiss alert and resume game
        print("Fire")
        self.timer.fire()
        refreshAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))
}
```

`action` is what is called when the game is paused. I first stop the timer with `timer.invalidate()`, and then display an alert which allows the user to confirm if they want to quit or not. If they say no, my goal is to resume the timer. The issue with this is that I'm forced to call `self`, which I believe conflicts with the pre-existing `timer.invalidate()` therefore resulting the timer to not `fire`. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to schedule a new timer

Answer (score 0):

Once an NSTimer is invalidated it cannot be reused.  You need to create a new one to resume it's firing cycle.

Comment: Alright I just created a new timer, however once i start it, it doesn't seem to pick up where it left off, it starts exactly `1` second after. So for example if the timer stopped at 1.25 seconds, it wouldn't pick up from where it left, it would wait another second then update. Any way I could pick up where I left?

Comment: depends if you're using a repeating timer or a one-shot timer.  when the timer is invalidated its fireDate still contains the time stamp of the last fire.  you can use that to reduce the time for the new timer.  If you're using a repeating timer, it will be a little trickier because you'll have to make a one-shot timer for the remaining time in the interval an only resume the repeating one after that.

Comment: I currently have it set to repeat

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new `timer`. Sadly you cannot just use `fire` to resume it.

```
func action() {
 //Paused
 timer.invalidate()

let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Quit?", message: "Are you sure you want to quit?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes!", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    //Quit
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No!", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    //Dismiss alert and resume game
    print("Fire")
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "timerOn", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    refreshAlert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}))
```

If u want to resume a `timer`, look a this question: [Resuming an NSTimer in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646158/resuming-an-nstimer-in-swift)

It involves using a `CADisplayLink` which is the only way who can resume a timer.